# how does async pipe know when to update

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-pipe

I have the following code to manage users,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  template: `
  <input [(ngModel)]="newUser"><button (click)="addNewUser()">add</button>
  <div *ngFor="let user of users$ |async">
    {{user}}
  </div>
  `
})
export class UserComponent {
  newUser: string;
  users$: Observable<any>;
  private _users = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users$ = of(this._users);
  }

  addNewUser() {
    this._users.push(this.newUser);
  }
}
```

How does angular know when to update this.users$ in the html when I simply push a new user to this._users array wrapped in rxjs `of`? How does angular async pipe detect changes inside an observable?

Comment: truth is that in this case `async` pipe won't detect changes. the `_users`  array is an object and as such observed by angular per default. try changing your change detection strategy and you will see that in fact the array won't be updated in your view

Comment: The async pipe has nothing to do with the detection of the pushed user. Because of the default change detection strategy, the click event in the button triggers change detection in the complete view.

Comment: @ggradnig,  `_users` is observed by angular, but not `of(_users)` since it has not changed after initialization, I don't understand how angular can know when to react to inner _users change.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, true there is change detection, but my question is that how angular knows to react to inner `_users` change since I did not use `_users directly` in html.

Comment: angular is accessing your array in short intervals and comparing it with the previous value, it's pretty much a brute force attack on all the data-bound variables. try the following: create a getter in your component (`get test()`) and put a `console.log` inside. you'll see how often angular tries to access your objects.

Comment: @ggradnig, thanks for the reply. but I don't see how getter is related to my question since it will try to access `of(_users)` in analogy. so basically I am familiar with `let user of _users`, but just confused by `let user of rxjs.of(_users)|async`. does angular detect the changes in `_users` and re-emit it to the outer observable under the hood?

Comment: no, the async pipe subscribes on your observable and this observable will emit exactly once. then, angular holds the reference to the emitted array and uses its default change detection strategy to update the array. in other words, if you remove both the observable and the async pipe you will get the exact same behaviour.

Comment: @ggradnig, thanks a lot. I understand now

Comment: you're welcome, wish you luck with angular and rxjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view the source code here

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts

It subscribes to the observable.

From the comments in the source

- Unwraps a value from an asynchronous primitive.
- The `async` pipe subscribes to an `Observable` or `Promise` and returns the latest value it has emitted.
- When a new value is emitted, the `async` pipe marks the component to be checked for changes.
- When the component gets destroyed, the `async` pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks.

Looking at your question you are abusing the point of observables. You should not be pushing a new value into the array, you should be making the observable emit a new array. The reason Angular is updating the page has nothing to do with observables but the fact you are using the default change detection strategy it notices the array has changed.

If you were using a BehaviorSubject instead of using of you could call next

```
addNewUser() {
  const users = this.users$.getValue();
  this.users$.next([...users, this.newUser]);
}
```

Observables allow you to use the more efficient on push change detection strategy which will not update the page with what you have done. You would need to replace the array with a new instance of an array for onPush to detect changes.