# How to add a new message to an array list when it's async pipe loaded?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm building a chat with `Socket.io`.
How to add a new message to an array list when it's async pipe loaded? Is it overcomplicated?
Should I use `subscribe` instead because is it easier?

**subscribe**

```
<ul class="chat-messages-show-list">
    <li *ngFor="let message of output">
      <p>
        <b>{{ message.userName }}</b>
      </p>
      {{ message.text }}
    </li>
</ul>

output: any[] = [];
this.chatService.listen('message-broadcast')
.subscribe((result) =>{
  this.output.push(result);
});
```

**async pipe**

```
<ul class="chat-messages-show-list">
  <ng-container *ngIf="(output$ | async) as output">
    <li *ngFor="let message of output">
      <p>
        <b>{{ message.userName }}</b>
      </p>
      {{ message.text }}
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>

output$!: Observable<any>;
//How to add a new message to an array list when it's async pipe loaded?
this.output$ = this.chatService.listen('message-broadcast');
```

`this.chatService.listen`: listen for the new message event (socket.io). It returns me `JSON` like below:

```
{
    userName: "username1",
    text: "Text Typed by User"
}
```

Comment: So the message broadcast returns a single message each time one is sent, not a list of messages?

Comment: Have original problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560704/how-does-async-pipe-know-when-to-update

Comment: Use behaviorsubject and pipe your chatService.listen services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) to accumulate all messages into an array:

**Component**:

```js
public messages$ = this.chatService.listen('message-broadcast').pipe(
    scan((all, message) => all.concat(message), [])
);
```

**Template**:

```html
<ul class="chat-messages-show-list">
  <li *ngFor="let message of messages$ | async">
    <p>
      <b>{{ message.userName }}</b>
    </p>
    {{ message.text }}
  </li>
</ul>
```